# Dynamic Drop down values based on another dropdown

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I have two tables in my Database. One is Department and other is Manager. I created a drop down in JSP and it shows list of Departments from Database. I want to show list of Managers in another dropdown based on Department selected. how to achieve this?

Here, I am referring to cascading dropdowns. Thanks you.

Comment: -1 and flagged as duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556368/department-managers-based-on-department-selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given no HTML or any script you have tried yourself as such the below should serve as a good template for you to get started.

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/wLMCZ/) - Cascading dropdowns, show managers for selected department

Assuming the following HTML

```
<div>
    <div style="float: left;">
        Select Department
        <br />
        <select id="departments"></select>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 10px;">
        Select Manager
        <br />
        <select id="managers"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

​
When you have loaded the departments and managers from the database you can dynamically populate the selects with code similar to this:

```
var $departments = $("#departments");
var $managers = $("#managers");

// This data would be loaded from the DB
var departments = [
    {id: "1", value: "Department 1"},
    {id: "2", value: "Department 2"}
];

// This data would be loaded from the DB
var managers = [
    { departmentId: "1", value: "Dep 1 Manager 1"},
    { departmentId: "1", value: "Dep 1 Manager 2"},
    { departmentId: "1", value: "Dep 1 Manager 3"},
    { departmentId: "1", value: "Dep 1 Manager 4"},
    { departmentId: "1", value: "Dep 1 Manager 5"},
    { departmentId: "1", value: "Dep 1 Manager 6"},
    { departmentId: "1", value: "Dep 1 Manager 7"},
    { departmentId: "1", value: "Dep 1 Manager 8"},
    { departmentId: "1", value: "Dep 1 Manager 9"},
    { departmentId: "1", value: "Dep 1 Manager 10"},
    { departmentId: "2", value: "Dep 2 Manager 1"},
    { departmentId: "2", value: "Dep 2 Manager 2"},
    { departmentId: "2", value: "Dep 2 Manager 3"},
    { departmentId: "2", value: "Dep 2 Manager 4"},
    { departmentId: "2", value: "Dep 2 Manager 5"},
    { departmentId: "2", value: "Dep 2 Manager 6"},
    { departmentId: "2", value: "Dep 2 Manager 7"},
    { departmentId: "2", value: "Dep 2 Manager 8"},
    { departmentId: "2", value: "Dep 2 Manager 9"},
    { departmentId: "2", value: "Dep 2 Manager 10"}
];

function getManagers() {
    $managers.empty();

    var departmentId = $departments.val();

    for (i = 0; i < managers.length; i++) {
        if (managers[i].departmentId === departmentId) {
            $managers.append("<option value='" + managers[i].departmentId + "'>" + managers[i].value + "</option>");
        }
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < departments.length; i++) {
    $departments.append("<option value='" + departments[i].id + "'>" + departments[i].value + "</option>");
}

getManagers();

$departments.on("change", function(){
    getManagers();
});
```

I have hard-coded the department and manager sources as I don't have a database.

Comment: Francois, the above code is showing errors. If I put the above code in JSP page, then it didn't work. It showed Javascript errors. error : "Object doesn't support this Property or method.

Comment: I assumed you needed a jQuery/JavaScript solution due to the associated tags. I don't know if all his would work in a JSP page. Try to pinpoint the exact line for the error and if it is any of the jQuery methods than your reference to jQuery is most likely missing. Also make sure your script code is encaspulated within a `$(document).ready(function(){// your code here...})`

Comment: I am getting the error : "Object doesn't support this Property or method at :  departments.forEach(function (department) {

Comment: @Nash: Are you using Internet Explorer by chance cause IE does not support `forEach`. I changed the code in the DEMO to use a regular `for` loop which should work now. I also updated the code displayed in the answer.

Comment: Yes, I am using IE. The changes that you made worked and thanks for your efforts and time in order to help me.

Comment: @Nash: No worries, in general to prevent getting questions closed as duplicates in the future, either edit your previous question or delete it if you had no response before creating a similar question. Saves a lot of hassle. Glad you got it sorted though :)

Comment: Sure, will follow the forum etiquette. Thank you.